# Create a named bean of type `java.lang.String` with request scoping in Spring MVC

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-bean

I have config class `SpecialEventsConfig`.

I am trying to initialise a request Scoped bean of type String.

---

```
    @Bean("requestTime")
    public String getRequestTime() {
        return String.valueOf(System.nanoTime());
    }
```

This works, but it will initialise a singleton. I want to use this to initialise a String for the request scope.

---

```
    @Bean("requestTime")
    @RequestScope(proxyMode = ScopedProxyMode.TARGET_CLASS)// Tried NO and INTERFACES as well
    public String getRequestTime() {
        return String.valueOf(System.nanoTime());
    }
```

This could solve my problem, but unfortunately it doesn't work.

---

Is there a way to achieve such behaviour?

Comment: No. Not with a `String`. For scoped proxies (as the name implies) a proxy needs to be created. It has to be a class proxy in this case and that simply isn't possible because `String` is `final`. However this looks like a case of going to far with dependency injection.

Comment: This is just an example.
I actually have a use-case where I get some string data using a network call and I want to make sure its available across components. Now I can achieve this be wrapping this within a custom class, but I was looking for a way to have a String bean created, to avoid creating a custom class.

Comment: Doesn't matter you simply cannot construct a scoped `String` regardless where it comes from.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you could try this workaround.

```java
@Bean("requestTime")
@RequestScope(proxyMode = ScopedProxyMode.TARGET_CLASS)
public Supplier<String> getRequestTime() {
    long time = System.nanoTime();
    return () -> String.valueOf(time);
}
```

Comment: This worked for me. Considering the Supplier is an interface, Spring would be able to create its CGLIB proxy.

Answer (score -1):

for using request scope for bean you can use either

```
@Scope(value = WebApplicationContext.SCOPE_REQUEST, proxyMode = ScopedProxyMode.TARGET_CLASS)
```

or

```
@RequestScope
```

Comment: That wouldn't help in this case as the bean being proxied is `final`.